# Решение конфликта слияния веток в git

Tags: git

На этой странице [Основы ветвления и слияния](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

в разделе слияния сказано:

> Это решение содержит понемногу из каждой части, и я полностью удалил строки <<<<<<<, ======= и >>>>>>

откуда именно нужно удалять эти строки? если я работаю с консолью git, это нужно удалять прямо в консоли? Или нужно удалять эти кавычки в редакторе кода?
Про это как-то ничего не сказано.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61638/discussion-on-question-by-word------git).